# Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, xml-configuration, gxp

I am running the Struts2 application in eclipse but it is displaying the error while running in the Apache Tomcat server the error I am getting is

```
    SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/projectdetails/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FieldError/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5508)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/projectdetails/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FieldError/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 19 more

Aug 29, 2014 11:47:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/projectdetails/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FieldError/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5508)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/projectdetails/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FieldError/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer class:org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer - bean - jar:file:/C:/projectdetails/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/FieldError/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)
    ... 19 more
```

I kept all the jar files in the lib folder in eclipse even though when I am trying to run the basic application it is getting the above error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by GXP plugin deployed with the application, if you are not using GXPs then remove it from classpath. The referenced class is `org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer` absent in the distribution. You might need additional libraries to satisfy dependency to use this plugin correctly. Certainly it is google-gxp, you can look up required libraries in the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-gxp-plugin/2.3.16.3).